# How to get only second line using awk

Tags: awk

Hello stack overflow community.

Wondering if you can help me with this.

I want to get the available storage space on a computer system and export it to a variable.

I know the command below will give me the available storage on a system.
export HOME=`cd;pwd`
df -H --output=avail ${HOME}

But it gives me a header of Avail

```
Avail
891G
```

I only want the `891G` to be exported as a string into a variable.

I tried this command below but it didn't work

```
df -H --output=avail ${HOME} | awk -F"\n" '{print$1}'
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know for a fact that you'll always be looking for the value in the 2nd line:

```
$ df -H --output=avail ${HOME} | awk 'NR==2'
   39G
```

To remove the leading space you have a few options; one small addition to the current `awk` idea:

```
$ df -H --output=avail ${HOME} | awk 'NR==2 {print $1}'
39G
```

Then storing in a variable:

```
$ size=$(df -H --output=avail ${HOME} | awk 'NR==2 {print $1}')
$ typeset -p size
declare -- size="39G"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F"\n" '{print $1}'
```

Will just print, without altering anything, as GNU `AWK` by default treat newlines are row separators, therefore there can not be newline inside row, therefore you will get whole row treated as single field. If you wish to have each line as field and there are not blank lines, then you might do so by setting row separator (`RS`) to empty string and field separator (`FS`) to newline, let `command` output be

```
Avail
891G
```

then

```
command | awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="\n"}{print $2}'
```

gives output

```
891G
```

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score -2):

```
jot 100 | mawk '_--{exit}_+=NR'

2
```

Comment: Adding some explanation to your answer will make it more valuable to future users and avoid its removal from the site.

Comment: @miken32 : feel free to remove the most succinct solution